# UPDATE > SET column to multiple values based on another table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, subquery, case

I would like to update DB table .AdditionalInfo with different values based upon which Key is given to the row (based on UI field), with data from two different columns LOINC.code & LOINC.relatedNames from a separate table .LOINC... I have written the query a few different ways and have looked at multiple posts already written to address individual problems I came across while writing this but have not found a way to successfully update to TEST fields, and this is what I have ended up with. Please let me know if any additional info would be beneficial. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! My query is below:

```
UPDATE
    Copia.Copia.AdditionalInfo ai
SET
    answerSting = CASE
                        WHEN ai.userDefinedQuestionKey = 60 
                            THEN LOINCCode.code
                        WHEN ai.userDefinedQuestionKey = 68
                            THEN LOINCSN.relatedNames
                        ELSE NULL
                    END
FROM
    (SELECT
        l.code,
        p.panelKey1
    FROM 
        Copia.Copia.AdditionalInfo ai
            Left Join Copia.Copia.Panel p
                ON ai.keyOne = p.PanelKey
            Left Join Copia.Copia.PanelTest pt
                ON p.panelKey = pt.panelTestKey
            Left Join Copia.Copia.LOINC l
                ON pt.loincKey = l.lOINCKey
    WHERE
        ai.keyOne = p.panelKey1
    ) LOINCCode

    Join
        (SELECT
            l.relatedNames,
            p.panelKey2
        FROM 
            Copia.Copia.AdditionalInfo ai
                Left Join Copia.Copia.Panel p
                    ON ai.keyOne = p.PanelKey
                Left Join Copia.Copia.PanelTest pt
                    ON p.panelKey = pt.panelTestKey
                Left Join Copia.Copia.LOINC l
                    ON pt.loincKey = l.lOINCKey
        WHERE
            ai.keyOne = p.panelKey2
        ) LOINCSN
WHERE
    ai.keyOne IN (LOINCCode.panelKey, LOINCSN.panelKey)
    
--  NOTES
    
    --  ai.keyOne = 478 (Specific Order Choice - TEST)
    --  ai.keyOneType = 6 (UserDefinedField Type = Order Choice - Not needed)
    --  ai.userDefinedQuestionKey = 60 (LOINC Code) & 68 (LOINC Short Name)
```

Below are samples of the AdditionalInfo & LOINC tables. Please let me know if this will work.

AdditionalInfo ai table houses user defined fields linked to multiple tables in DB. I am concerned with ai where it is linked to Panel p table. We get desired info from LOINC l table where is Joined to Panel p through PanelTest pt table, from which I only needed to Join the two.

My desired output would be to take the LOINC.Code & the LOINC.relatedNames and update the AdditionalInfo ai table where ai.keyOne = Panel.panelKey & ai.keyOneType = 6 (Panel Table) where ai.userDefinedQuestionKey is 60 for LOINC.code & 68 for LOINC.relatedNames. I hope this makes sense...

| l.answerString | l.keyOne | l.keyOneType | l.userDefinedQuestionKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 49D2060159 | 478 | 6 | 52 |
| U | 478 | 6 | 62 |
| 94500-6 | 478 | 6 | 60 |
| SARS-CoV-2 RNA Resp Ql NAA+probe | 478 | 6 | 68 |
| U | 478 | 6 | 61 |
| 4060 Innslake Dr | 478 | 6 | 54 |
| Glen Allen | 478 | 6 | 55 |
| 866-704-3113 | 478 | 6 | 59 |
| 804-346-4363 | 478 | 6 | 58 |
| VA | 478 | 6 | 56 |
| 23060 | 478 | 6 | 57 |
| RCA Laboratory Services LLC dba GENETWORx | 478 | 6 | 53 |
|  | 478 | 6 | 67 |
| LIMS | 478 | 6 | 66 |
|  | 478 | 6 | 65 |
| nasopharyngeal | 478 | 6 | 70 |
| 49D2060159 | 479 | 6 | 52 |
| U | 479 | 6 | 62 |
| 94845-5 | 479 | 6 | 60 |
| SARS-CoV-2 RNA Sal Ql NAA+probe | 479 | 6 | 68 |
| U | 479 | 6 | 61 |
| 4060 Innslake Dr | 479 | 6 | 54 |
| Glen Allen | 479 | 6 | 55 |
| 866-704-3113 | 479 | 6 | 59 |
| 804-346-4363 | 479 | 6 | 58 |
| VA | 479 | 6 | 56 |
| 23060 | 479 | 6 | 57 |
| RCA Laboratory Services LLC dba GENETWORx | 479 | 6 | 53 |
|  | 479 | 6 | 67 |
| LIMS | 479 | 6 | 66 |
|  | 479 | 6 | 65 |
| Saliva | 479 | 6 | 70 |

| p.name | p.panelKey | l.additionalInfoKey | l.answerString | l.keyOne | l.keyOneType | l.userDefinedQuestionKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 515 | APS | 478 | 2 | 34 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 516 | Kevin Aufdenkamp | 478 | 2 | 33 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10064 | 49D2060159 | 478 | 6 | 52 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10065 | U | 478 | 6 | 62 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10066 | 94500-6 | 478 | 6 | 60 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10067 | SARS-CoV-2 RNA Resp Ql NAA+probe | 478 | 6 | 68 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10068 | U | 478 | 6 | 61 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10069 | 4060 Innslake Dr | 478 | 6 | 54 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10070 | Glen Allen | 478 | 6 | 55 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10071 | 866-704-3113 | 478 | 6 | 59 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10072 | 804-346-4363 | 478 | 6 | 58 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10073 | VA | 478 | 6 | 56 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10074 | 23060 | 478 | 6 | 57 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10075 | RCA Laboratory Services LLC dba GENETWORx | 478 | 6 | 53 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10076 |  | 478 | 6 | 67 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10077 | LIMS | 478 | 6 | 66 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10078 |  | 478 | 6 | 65 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 10079 | nasopharyngeal | 478 | 6 | 70 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 24934 | 925987813187 925987813198 | 478 | 11 | 47 |
| SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) Aptima (Panther) | 478 | 46577 | Insurance Bill | 478 | 2 | 85 |

Comment: What would really help is table definitions and sample data in addition to what the desired output would be.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for the input. I will add these items to the question shortly.

Comment: Images for data are useless. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Apologies, this is only my second post. I will keep accessible sample data in mind for the future. I have removed the images and added tables based on the instructions received. Please let me know if this question can be improved.